# MS VSTS how do I add/modify fields in a Work Item

Tags: azure-devops, customization

I have a question regarding MS Visualstudio.com How do I add/modify field in a WorkItem?

I have tried to do it but when I go into the Process area which is where I believe I should be able to customise it all the options are greyed out.

Is it possible and what permissions do I need?

Cheers

Comment: Have you referred to the documentation on modifying process templates? The process for modifying work item templates is explained in great detail.

Answer (score 1):

If it's all grayed-out, it's probably (except if it's a rights management issue) because you're trying to modify one of the standard process, which you can't do. You have to create a new process that inherits from the process you're using

1. Go to the root of VSTS by clicking on the black VSTS logo on the
   top-left corner
2. Click on the parameters wheel
3. Click on Process
4. If you already have a custom process, click on it, otherwise, click on the "..." menu of the process you're currently using and select "Create inherited process
5. Select the work item type that you want to modify and do the modifications there
6. Go back to your project settings and change the process used to the new inherited process you created

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of processes in VSTS:

- **System processes** —Scrum, Agile, and CMMI— which are locked from being changed.
- **Inherited processes**, which you can customize and that inherit definitions from the system process from which they were created. System processes are owned and updated periodically by Microsoft. Any updates made to a system process will automatically update your inherited process.

If you want to customize a system process, it's not allowed, you have to create an inherited process. Also, you must be a member of the **Project Collection Administrators** group, the organization owner, or be granted explicit permissions to edit, create, or manage a specific process and to create a project.

Useful links for your reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/settings/work/inheritance-process-model?view=vsts
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-wit?view=vsts